# iOS7 UITableViewStyleGrouped section header font style name?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

All the answers I've seen so far are basically for pre-iOS7 (using `systemFontStyle` or `boldSystemFontStyle`).  That doesn't correspond to the default capitalized section title font in `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

I've had to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method that return the custom section header view and want to know the font Apple uses to capitalize section titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS7+, the default grouped table header view uses a UILabel with its text capitalized and systemFontSize:15.
The header height is 50.

How to recreate default grouped headers:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 200, 20)];
    [label setText:[[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section] uppercaseString]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the font size for the default plain tableview?

Comment: I know where and how to find it, but I would just try 12, 13 and 14 instead